# three.js Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in render loop

Tags: javascript, three.js

Ok.. so new to JS and three.js and I am very curious to know why I'm getting a stack exceedance in a function self call, that three.js naturally calls per design. Yet it only happens when I remove the call out of the main function.

I have basically taken the cube example from [three.js-Documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/manual/introduction/Creating-a-scene.html) and I am trying to setup the animation so I can dynamically add and subtract objects from the scene as well as send it to a specific canvas.

Original Code from three.js

```
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( cube );

        camera.position.z = 5;

        var render = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame( render );

            cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
            cube.rotation.y += 0.1;

            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        render();
```

Focusing in on the animation call `render();` is self called in `reqestAnimationFrame()` function. To break down the program structure for future use, I set it out like this (In hind sight not the best option):

```
function e3Dview(){
    // Set the e Canvas
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("eplot3D")

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, this.canvas.width / this.canvas.height, 0.1, 1000 );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: eplot3D });
    renderer.setSize( this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    var geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
    mat.wireframe = true
    this.cube = new THREE.Mesh( geo, mat );
    scene.add( this.cube );

    camera.position.z = 5;

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

    // Execute render
    this.renderloop();

};

e3Dview.prototype.renderloop = function(){
    requestAnimationFrame( this.renderloop() );

    this.cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    this.cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

};

e3Dview.prototype.sceneClear = function(){
     scene.children.forEach(function(object){
        scene.remove(object);
    });
};
```

Once I move the rendering loop outside the inital parent call I get a "stackoverflow" error....

**Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

So my question is how is it that when render calls itself in the **requestAnimationFrame** that's ok, but when the same thing happens outside the parent call the stack is not cleared and it fails?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

```
requestAnimationFrame( this.renderloop() );
```

Here you are effectively calling renderloop() immediately, instead of passing the function as a callback to requestAnimationFrame, thus causing an infinite recursion loop.

Naturally one might try to change it to the following, but that won't work either, because the function prototype being passed isn't bound to any object:

```
requestAnimationFrame( this.renderloop ); // This won't work, either.
```

A solution here is to bind the function to the scope of the object:

```
requestAnimationFrame( this.renderloop.bind(this) ); // This will work, but overhead at 60FPS might not be worth it
```

I recommend moving the renderloop function into the e3Dview constructor as a private method, like so:

```
function e3Dview(){
    var $this = this; // Hold the current object's scope, for accessing properties from within the callback method.

    ...

    function renderloop() {
        requestAnimationFrame( renderloop );

        $this.cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        $this.cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    renderloop();
}
```

It's not as pretty, but that's generally how it's done. If you really need to expose renderloop as a public function, you could -- but I suspect there isn't any reason to do so.

Comment: Thank you mate, that closes a few gaps in my JS knowledge. Really helpful.